# How to update new version of application in a running Ubuntu EC2 machine programmatically

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, aws-cloudformation

How can I update the new versions of application in my ubuntu machines in private subnet which are in Autoscaling. I am using cloudfromation script to bring up the entire set up. Can I include any script in cloudfromation template to do this?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish the upgrade.  Many people use amazon's provided script, cfn-hup. The way I do it is different and is as follows:

1. When instance launches, have script install application from files fetched from S3
2. Update S3 with new version.
3. Use a script(or manually) to shutdown instances one at a time, waiting for autoscaling to bring them up with the new version installed.